# limit on infinity of trigonometric function Sin x

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

i am make the follow limit with definition limit $\epsilon - \delta$

$ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{(x + 10\sin x )}$

but i don't know find a $A\in \mathbb R$ that $\forall_{x>A}$ $f(x)>M$  for all $M>0$

how is the treatment  with this functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $x+10\sin x \ge x-10$.